# Suggested practice to save a DB object in a view controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am coming from python/django, where I am used to doing this in a view, and django takes care of all the db magic in the background:

```
def register(request, email, password):
    User.objects.create(email=email, password=password)
    // Or, could do: user = User(); user.email = email; user.password=password; user.save()
    return redirect(...)
```

In java/spring, I'm trying to figure out the best practice of doing the above. Here is what I have right now:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Session sessionOne = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sessionOne.beginTransaction();

    //Create new user object
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    user.saveUser(name, email, password);
    sessionOne.save(user);

    sessionOne.getTransaction().commit();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();

}
```

And my `UserEntity` looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    private String email;
    private String password;

    public null saveUser(String name, String email, String password) {

        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
}
```

Is the above the correct way to do this? Specifically, as to the following:

- Do I need to create a session via a HibernateUtil and shut it down on every view request?
- Do I need to begin a session, save a session, and then commit the transaction each time?
- Where should I be putting the save/transaction methods, in the view controller, or in the UserEntity, or somewhere else?

The above seems very convoluted to me: I think it would be easier to query the database directly rather than do all the session creation, saving, destruction, etc everytime I open up a new view. What would be the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Data to communicate with Hibernate.

An outdated example: https://github.com/azee/spring-boot-jpa-example

You will create repositories classes for each of your entities. All DB interaction will be implemented there. In most cases implementation provided by Spring Data is enough.

Try to keep your controllers manage business logic. Database interactions should be managed by a separate module. Imagine if you'd like to change your db from Postgre to Mongo? You'll have to replace the DB layer only. Plus you decouple business logic and DB internals.

Comment: what is the location of the "Spring Data" section? Is that in services, or where should I look in your repository? Perhaps post an example in the answer and I'll accept it? Also, would you mind explaining what the four directories are here? beans, controller, services, and dal?

Comment: Spring Data is a commonly used lib. You can just google it. http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/#quick-start

Comment: I split all my applications to logical parts. Beans - objects in the system. E.g. - entities. Service - a business logic layer. Dal - data access layer - the communication with database.  Once again - it is an outdated repo. Look for fresh spring data tutorials.